# Vim copy to system clipboard works but can't paste on the same terminal

Tags: ubuntu, vim, terminal, clipboard, copy-paste

I can copy text into the system clipboard in vim.
Assume that vim was opened in terminal window A.
I can paste the text in terminal window B but can't paste in terminal A.
Also once I try to paste in terminal A, then the data seems to be cleared from the clipboard, I can't paste anymore in terminal B.

Has anyone come across this issue or know what might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your experience may very enormously depending what x-terminal emulator you use and if you use a terminal multiplexer (and which).

One of the methods of copying to/fro vim/terminal that often works is performing both operations (copying and pasting) with `SHIFT` key pressed.

Above works if you do not use `CTRL+c`/`CTRL+v` for copy paste, which means you only use selecting with left mouse click&drag and pasting with middle click.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:sh` to turn back to terminal and `CTRL+D` to vim.

In my case **I can't** use `CTRL+Z` and `fg` to paste what I have copied.